# how to create this query string in java createQuery?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, native

I am trying to use Hibernate or native SQL or java to return a list of `Product` objects, but I can not get the code working, I appreciate if anybody help me, thanks a lot,
    This is the logic:

```
 ...
 ArrayList<Product> prodList = new ArrayList<Product>();
EntityManager entityManager = this.entityManager;
try 
{

  //the logic of following query is: select all records from prodTable table where productDate is
//passed 2 months than today's date(something list today's day minus productDate is 2 months), 
//and then the records are not existed in prodCategory table by the key of ProductID and 
//productCategory combination. So the prodList is the combination of the above two conditions. 
//something like this:

 String queryString = "select p from prodTable p where (today - p.ProductDate) greaterThan 2  
months AND p is not in (select c from prodCategory c where c.ProductID = p.ProductID and 
c.category = '09' ) //need help of this line of query.

 prodList = entityManager.createQuery(queryString).getResultList();
 return prodList;
} catch (Exception e) {

throw e;
```

}
...

Comment: It looks like you have a string that doesn't have an end quotation mark.  And what, specifically, are you running into as an issue?

Comment: my queryString sample code is just a sample to show you what I wanted, this code does not compile, I need help to write a complete of this code:String queryString = "select p from prodTable p where (today - p.ProductDate) greaterThan 2  
months AND p is not in (select c from prodCategory c where c.ProductID = p.ProductID and 
c.category = '09' )

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
 ...
 ArrayList<Product> prodList = new ArrayList<Product>();
EntityManager entityManager = this.entityManager;
try 
{

 String queryString = "select p from prodTable p where (today - p.ProductDate) greaterThan 2  
months AND p is not in (select c from prodCategory c where c.ProductID = p.ProductID and 
c.category = '09' )"; //need help of this line of query.

 prodList = entityManager.createSQLQuery(queryString).getResultList();
 return prodList;
} catch (Exception e) {

throw e;
}
```

`Note:` I have used SQLQuery, hence you can place your query as you've written it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but before I testing, I donot think your code will be working, basically, you just add )" at the end of my codes, like I said, my codes is just a sample, it is not compile at all, for example: "greaterThan" , "is not in" etc. I just want to give you an idea what I wanted,  we need to completely re-write it, please let me know if you have any idea to write a completely compiable codes. thanks again.